# Second monitor on Linux not recognized

Tags: linux, drivers, amd-radeon, x-server

I have a dual monitor Linux system. In the past, I had a much lessor, no-name graphics card and was able to get this to work. However, when I switched to AMD Radeon, it (Linux/Drivers/Mesa?) does not recognize my second monitor. The card seems to work for one and only one monitor, despite supporting 4 plugs. I'd like to run lxrandr and tell it to make 2 monitors 1 big wide monitor (effectively). Please note, I know how to do that (if only the drivers/linux/?) would work.

The card I have has 4 plugs (2 HDMI and 2 Display). Both monitors are Display. I have tried switching display cables and monitors. If I take the cable from the card to the working monitor and change monitors to the other one, the other one still works. It is not the monitor, and nor is it the display port cable. I'd like to run lxrandr and set the monitor/display for the second monitor, but it only shows one.

Here are commands that I've used to gather info about my system.

```
$ uname -a
```

```
$ lspci |grep VGA
0c:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. \[AMD/ATI\] Navi 23 \[Radeon RX 6600/6600 XT/6600M\] (rev c1)
```

(I ran this to strongly suggest the graphics card is being used)

```
$ glxgears
17627 frames in 5.0 seconds = 3523.677 FPS
X connection to :0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
```

```
$ xrandr --listmonitors
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Monitors: 1
 0: +\*default 1920/508x1080/286+0+0  default
```

```
$ xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 0
```

I tried installing the setup as below, but this didn't help.

```
$ sudo apt list --installed |grep amdgpu
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
amdgpu-core/unknown,now 20.45-1188099 all \[installed,automatic\]
amdgpu-dkms-firmware/unknown,now 1:5.6.20.906316-1188099 all \[installed,automatic\]
amdgpu-dkms/unknown,now 1:5.6.20.906316-1188099 all \[installed\]
amdgpu-install/focal,focal,now 22.20.50200-1438746\~20.04 all \[installed\]
amdgpu-lib32/unknown,now 20.45-1188099 amd64 \[installed\]
amdgpu-lib/unknown,now 20.45-1188099 amd64 \[installed\]
amdgpu-pin/unknown,now 20.45-1188099 all \[installed\]
amdgpu/unknown,now 20.45-1188099 amd64 \[installed\]
gst-omx-amdgpu/unknown,now 1.0.0.1-1188099 amd64 \[installed,automatic\]
libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1/unknown,now 1:2.4.100-1188099 amd64 \[installed,automatic\]
libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1/unknown,now 1:2.4.100-1188099 i386 \[installed,automatic\]
libdrm-amdgpu-common/unknown,now 1.0.0-1188099 all \[installed,automatic\]
libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1/unknown,now 1:2.4.100-1188099 amd64 \[installed,automatic\]
libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1/unknown,now 1:2.4.100-1188099 i386 \[installed,automatic\]
libdrm-amdgpu1/focal-updates,focal-security,now 2.4.107-8ubuntu1\~20.04.2 amd64 \[installed\]
libdrm-amdgpu1/focal-updates,focal-security,now 2.4.107-8ubuntu1\~20.04.2 i386 \[installed,automatic\]
libdrm2-amdgpu/unknown,now 1:2.4.100-1188099 amd64 \[installed,automatic\]
libdrm2-amdgpu/unknown,now 1:2.4.100-1188099 i386 \[installed,automatic\]
libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 amd64 \[installed,automatic\]
libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 i386 \[installed,automatic\]
libegl1-amdgpu-mesa/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 amd64 \[installed,automatic\]
libegl1-amdgpu-mesa/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 i386 \[installed,automatic\]
libgbm1-amdgpu/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 amd64 \[installed,automatic\]
libgbm1-amdgpu/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 i386 \[installed,automatic\]
libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 amd64 \[installed,automatic\]
libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 i386 \[installed,automatic\]
libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 amd64 \[installed,automatic\]
libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 i386 \[installed,automatic\]
libglapi-amdgpu-mesa/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 amd64 \[installed,automatic\]
libglapi-amdgpu-mesa/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 i386 \[installed,automatic\]
libgles1-amdgpu-mesa/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 amd64 \[installed,automatic\]
libgles1-amdgpu-mesa/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 i386 \[installed,automatic\]
libgles2-amdgpu-mesa/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 amd64 \[installed,automatic\]
libgles2-amdgpu-mesa/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 i386 \[installed,automatic\]
libllvm10.0-amdgpu/unknown,now 1:10.0-1188099 amd64 \[installed,automatic\]
libllvm10.0-amdgpu/unknown,now 1:10.0-1188099 i386 \[installed,automatic\]
libosmesa6-amdgpu/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 amd64 \[installed,automatic\]
libosmesa6-amdgpu/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 i386 \[installed,automatic\]
libxatracker2-amdgpu/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 amd64 \[installed,automatic\]
libxatracker2-amdgpu/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 i386 \[installed,automatic\]
mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 amd64 \[installed,automatic\]
mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 amd64 \[installed,automatic\]
mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 i386 \[installed,automatic\]
mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 amd64 \[installed,automatic\]
mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 i386 \[installed,automatic\]
xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu/unknown,now 1:19.1.0-1188099 amd64 \[installed,automatic\]
xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu/focal,now 19.1.0-1 amd64 \[installed\]
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
amdgpu-core/unknown,now 20.45-1188099 all \[installed,automatic\]
amdgpu-dkms-firmware/unknown,now 1:5.6.20.906316-1188099 all \[installed,automatic\]
amdgpu-dkms/unknown,now 1:5.6.20.906316-1188099 all \[installed\]
amdgpu-install/focal,focal,now 22.20.50200-1438746\~20.04 all \[installed\]
amdgpu-lib32/unknown,now 20.45-1188099 amd64 \[installed\]
amdgpu-lib/unknown,now 20.45-1188099 amd64 \[installed\]
amdgpu-pin/unknown,now 20.45-1188099 all \[installed\]
amdgpu/unknown,now 20.45-1188099 amd64 \[installed\]
gst-omx-amdgpu/unknown,now 1.0.0.1-1188099 amd64 \[installed,automatic\]
libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1/unknown,now 1:2.4.100-1188099 amd64 \[installed,automatic\]
libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1/unknown,now 1:2.4.100-1188099 i386 \[installed,automatic\]
libdrm-amdgpu-common/unknown,now 1.0.0-1188099 all \[installed,automatic\]
libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1/unknown,now 1:2.4.100-1188099 amd64 \[installed,automatic\]
libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1/unknown,now 1:2.4.100-1188099 i386 \[installed,automatic\]
libdrm-amdgpu1/focal-updates,focal-security,now 2.4.107-8ubuntu1\~20.04.2 amd64 \[installed\]
libdrm-amdgpu1/focal-updates,focal-security,now 2.4.107-8ubuntu1\~20.04.2 i386 \[installed,automatic\]
libdrm2-amdgpu/unknown,now 1:2.4.100-1188099 amd64 \[installed,automatic\]
libdrm2-amdgpu/unknown,now 1:2.4.100-1188099 i386 \[installed,automatic\]
libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 amd64 \[installed,automatic\]
libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 i386 \[installed,automatic\]
libegl1-amdgpu-mesa/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 amd64 \[installed,automatic\]
libegl1-amdgpu-mesa/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 i386 \[installed,automatic\]
libgbm1-amdgpu/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 amd64 \[installed,automatic\]
libgbm1-amdgpu/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 i386 \[installed,automatic\]
libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 amd64 \[installed,automatic\]
libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 i386 \[installed,automatic\]
libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 amd64 \[installed,automatic\]
libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 i386 \[installed,automatic\]
libglapi-amdgpu-mesa/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 amd64 \[installed,automatic\]
libglapi-amdgpu-mesa/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 i386 \[installed,automatic\]
libgles1-amdgpu-mesa/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 amd64 \[installed,automatic\]
libgles1-amdgpu-mesa/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 i386 \[installed,automatic\]
libgles2-amdgpu-mesa/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 amd64 \[installed,automatic\]
libgles2-amdgpu-mesa/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 i386 \[installed,automatic\]
libllvm10.0-amdgpu/unknown,now 1:10.0-1188099 amd64 \[installed,automatic\]
libllvm10.0-amdgpu/unknown,now 1:10.0-1188099 i386 \[installed,automatic\]
libosmesa6-amdgpu/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 amd64 \[installed,automatic\]
libosmesa6-amdgpu/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 i386 \[installed,automatic\]
libxatracker2-amdgpu/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 amd64 \[installed,automatic\]
libxatracker2-amdgpu/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 i386 \[installed,automatic\]
mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 amd64 \[installed,automatic\]
mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 amd64 \[installed,automatic\]
mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 i386 \[installed,automatic\]
mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 amd64 \[installed,automatic\]
mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers/unknown,now 1:20.1.6-1188099 i386 \[installed,automatic\]
xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu/unknown,now 1:19.1.0-1188099 amd64 \[installed,automatic\]
xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu/focal,now 19.1.0-1 amd64 \[installed\]
```

```
$ glxinfo | egrep -i 'Direct|String'
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.1, 256 bits)
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.1.6
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
GL\_AMD\_gpu\_shader\_int64, GL\_AMD\_multi\_draw\_indirect, 
GL\_ARB\_derivative\_control, GL\_ARB\_direct\_state\_access, 
GL\_ARB\_draw\_elements\_base\_vertex, GL\_ARB\_draw\_indirect, 
GL\_ARB\_half\_float\_vertex, GL\_ARB\_indirect\_parameters, 
GL\_ARB\_multi\_draw\_indirect, GL\_ARB\_occlusion\_query2, 
OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 20.1.6
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.40
GL\_AMD\_multi\_draw\_indirect, GL\_AMD\_query\_buffer\_object, 
GL\_ARB\_direct\_state\_access, GL\_ARB\_draw\_buffers, 
GL\_ARB\_draw\_indirect, GL\_ARB\_draw\_instanced, GL\_ARB\_enhanced\_layouts, 
GL\_ARB\_indirect\_parameters, GL\_ARB\_instanced\_arrays, 
GL\_ARB\_map\_buffer\_range, GL\_ARB\_multi\_bind, GL\_ARB\_multi\_draw\_indirect, 
GL\_EXT\_direct\_state\_access, GL\_EXT\_draw\_buffers2, GL\_EXT\_draw\_instanced, 
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 20.1.6
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
```